# Hide elements in a Datatables.net table, based on data in another column

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable where I recently changed to using the AJAX data source approach.
It works a treat.
I have added three buttons to the first column (works, no problem) and now I want to conditionally display / hide the third button based on the data in another column. I don't want to display the third button if data: PublishStatus = "No shifts created"

I have looked at: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html

but cannot wrap my head around what is needed to twist it to my situation, since the condition is based on a column other than the one that i am using. I could see how to do it if i was placing the button in the PublishStatus column

```
"ajax": "dt-data_list_wo.asp?mf=d",
        "columns": [
        {"data": "GUID" , render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          return type === 'display'  ?
          '<span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="requestwo.asp"><input type="hidden" name="itemGUID" value="'+ data +'"/><input type="hidden" name="action" value="wodetails"  /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-right: 5px">Details</button></form></span><span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="prepub.asp"><input type="hidden" name = "itemguid" value = "' + data + '"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="view"  /><input type="hidden" name="backlink" value="listwo.asp"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-warning" style="margin-right: 5px">View RS</button></form></span><span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="prepub.asp"><input type="hidden" name = "itemguid" value = "' + data + '"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="publish_shifts"  /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger">Publish</button></form></span>': data;
        }},
        { "data": "PublishStatus" },
        { "data": "orgname" },
        { "data": "woref" },
        { "data": "weeknum" },
        { "data": "startdate" },
        { "data": "client_po" },
        { "data": "work_desc" }
    ],
```

Comment: Look at the contents of the `row` variable in your `render` function. That contains all the data items in the current row (probably as an array of objects, in your case). So in your `render` function you can expand your conditional logic to refer to `row.PublishStatus`. Use `console.log( row );` to double-check how your row data is structured.

Comment: Thanks, that was just the hint i needed. Revised code posted below

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to andrewjames, the solution involved a couple of changes to my original code - i have commented out the parts that prevented it from working and the if clause with row.PublishStatus really did the trick. Made my weekend!

```
"ajax": "dt-data_list_wo.asp?mf=d",
        "columns": [
        {"data": "GUID" , render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          //return type === 'display' ?
          if (row.PublishStatus == "All shifts published" || row.PublishStatus == "No shifts created yet") {
          return '<span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="requestwo.asp"><input type="hidden" name="itemGUID" value="'+ data +'"/><input type="hidden" name="action" value="wodetails"  /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-right: 5px">Details</button></form></span><span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="prepub.asp"><input type="hidden" name = "itemguid" value = "' + data + '"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="view"  /><input type="hidden" name="backlink" value="listwo.asp"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-warning" style="margin-right: 5px">View RS</button></form></span>'//: data;
          } else {
          return '<span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="requestwo.asp"><input type="hidden" name="itemGUID" value="'+ data +'"/><input type="hidden" name="action" value="wodetails"  /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" style="margin-right: 5px">Details</button></form></span><span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="prepub.asp"><input type="hidden" name = "itemguid" value = "' + data + '"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="view"  /><input type="hidden" name="backlink" value="listwo.asp"/><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-warning" style="margin-right: 5px">View RS</button></form></span><span style="display: inline-block;"><form method="POST" action="prepub.asp"><input type="hidden" name = "itemguid" value = "' + data + '"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="publish_shifts"  /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger">Publish</button></form></span>'//: data;
            }
        }},
        { "data": "PublishStatus" },
        { "data": "orgname" },
        { "data": "woref" },
        { "data": "weeknum" },
        { "data": "startdate" },
        { "data": "client_po" },
        { "data": "work_desc" }
    ],
```